# Drag and drop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu which is running in a virtual machine is not working

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, vmware

I have installed VMware Tools, but it is still not working. While installing VMware Tools it says I have to have some packages like make, source kernel (I don't remember the exact package names) and a few other packages to enable some features in VMware. I installed those also, but I'm still not able to drag and drop files from the Windows 7 host to the Ubuntu guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_dragndrop.html

http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-81932397-8211-499E-925E-98FC73428636.html

Which version of VMWare are you running? Have you enabled the sharing of a temp folder? IIRC you need to have one share enabled for this to work. Hope the above link helps.

Comment: Version 7.1 and i have enabled VMware-> settings ->options -> shared folders and i have given a folder in win 7 in that field. i dont know how it works.