# Can't drag-drop from Windows 10 to Ubuntu VirtualBox machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Trying to drag/drop (or copy/paste) files or folders **from my Windows-10 (x86-64)** machine to an ubuntu VirtualBox machine. It does not work.

My VirtualBox version is: 5.1.26 r117224. Guest machine is Ubuntu 16.0.4.2 64-bit and the host machine is Windows 10 64-bit.

### Initial setup steps:

1. "Shared-clipboard" and "drag-and-drop" are set to `bidirectional` in the VM's advanced settings.
2. From the host's device menu, I made sure that drag and drop option is set to `bidrectional`.
3. The "`Guest Additions CD image`" wizard installed on the host.

### What I've tried:

- sudo apt-get upgrade.
- sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso.
- Go to display setting, under video capture, check enable video capture.
- sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils.
- restart virtual machine.

Nothing made it work. There are two unanswered posts here:
[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/706782/drag-and-drop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu-which-is-running-in-a-virtual-machine-is) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/817229/copy-paste-and-drag-drop-does-not-work-from-host-to-guest-in-ubuntu-virtual-box).

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: One of the questions you linked to involves VMWare, not VirtualBox.

Comment: Potentially Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/723680/how-do-i-enable-virtualbox-shared-clipboard-drag-and-drop

Comment: Something tells me [it's working as designed](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/81)

Comment: I highly recommend using the current version of Vbox.  Avoids the possibility it is a potential known issue in that particular release you are using.

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: Side-note: have you tried subversion linux on Windows?

Comment: People might not be answering your question because there are a lot of top-ranked google answers to this question: setting up drag-and-drop is easy to solve.  Do you have an error message?  Where are you experiencing a problem setting this up?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575056/bidirectional-dragn-drop-is-not-working-with-virtualbox-and-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: You should install guest additions on the VM not on the host.

Answer (score 0):

You should install guest additions on the VM not on the host.

You installed guest additions on "the device itself", which seems to mean you installed guest additions on Windows 10 (the host system).

You need to install guest additions on your VM (the target machine).  So, you need to install guest additions for Ubuntu.

Ubuntu recommends using its official guides because they are maintained.  This is as link: [Guest Additions at Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/GuestAdditions).